# c++ 2017 <filesystem> stem() vs filename()

Tags: c++17

In c++  what's the difference between [stem()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/path/stem) and [filename()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/path/filename)

Both seem to do the same thing, except stem() returns "" if there is no file, but an empty folder?

I would prefer to use filename(), is there any good usecase of can stem()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`stem()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/path/stem) returns

> the substring from the beginning of `filename()` up to and not including the last period (`.`) character.

i.e. the filename *without* the extension (if there is an extension, otherwise it returns the same thing as `filename()`)

In fact, for any path `p`, [`p.stem() + p.extension() == p.filename()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/path/extension)